Is Swift calling the wrong function when two functions are too similar in name and parameter types?
I have two functions, each with the same name. The parameters are almost identical, but one function refers to a specific class while the other refers to a base class of that specific class. Swift compiles this to create an infinite recursion when the second function with the base class parameter is called. It should compile this to call the "correct" function (the first one) based on the parameter type. In this code, note that Element is the base class of Spline. The call to the second botom function ends with a crash due to the recursion when a Spline object is passed as the element parameter:
func getArea( of spline: Spline, areaType: AreaType, scale: Scale ) -> Rect {
    let area = spline.getArea( areaType: areaType )
    if !area.isEmpty {
        let renderArea = scale.toDestination( from: area )
        if areaType == .selection {
            return renderArea.inflated( by: scale.toDestinationUnits( from: StaticDrawingParameters.controlKnobRadius ) * 2.0 )
        } else {
            return renderArea
        }
        //return renderArea
    }
    return area
}

func getArea( of element: Element, areaType: AreaType, scale: Scale ) -> Rect? {
    if let spline = element as? Spline {
        return getArea( of: spline, areaType: areaType, scale: scale )
    }
    return nil
}

When the second function gets called with an Element reference that happens to be a Spline, it correctly converts the Element to a Spline reference (according the debugger) and then calls the getArea() function that it's already in. It does not use the other getArea() function, even though it has a parameter that is a Spline and not an Element.
I'm trying to find my mistake or determine that the compiler can't handle this properly.
The code is designed this way because I use an array of various types of Element objects that I need to process (I've removed some of their code for clarity). Each of the derived types derives from Element and each has the area computed differently. The area calculation also involves using information about the output device (screen, printer, file in some weird text format, etc.) so the data objects won't know how to do this themselves. Otherwise these would have been member functions in the various element classes.
Is there a mistake in the code, or my thinking that the compile should correctly pick what function to call based on the parameter type?
I'll change the parameter names to get around this problem, but I would rather fix it if it's a mistake I made that causes this.

The easiest way forward is probably to simply rename the second function (and maybe also make the other type specific ones private if possible)

I did that, but knowing what I missed might be useful.

First, please don't do this. If you're going to use inheritance, use inheritance:
class Element {
    func area(type: AreaType, scale: Scale) -> Rect? { nil }
}
class Spline: Element {
    override func area(type: AreaType, scale: Scale) -> Rect { ... }
}

But the reason your solution doesn't work is that these are not actually that similar. They have different return types. So, given this line:
    return getArea( of: spline, areaType: areaType, scale: scale )

The compiler wants a Rect? at this point. It looks for a getArea(of:areaType:scale:) that returns a Rect? and there is only one. You're hoping that it'll also perform Optional promotion on a method that returns Rect, but it doesn't do that. It already found a method that returns precisely what it wants.
You can fix this by making your signatures actually match and have the Spline version return Rect?. But a better solution is to use inheritance directly. Then the Optional promotion is not ambiguous. Note in my inheritance above, Spline.area returns a non-Optional. The promotion is made explicit due to override.
(That said, I do recommend avoiding class inheritance in Swift, and generally prefer protocols and structs for this kind of thing. But inheritance does work. The protocol version of this would not need Element; it would just have something like "AreaProviding". If you find yourself with a default implementation that returns nil to mean "doesn't have that," you often haven't really set your types up correctly.)

You caught the cause of the problem, and it was my mistake that I didn't see the return values being different. That solved it.
The data objects don't have visibility of the drawing code and therefore cannot know how to calculate their area. They do know their area in regards to the cordinate system but they don't know about font sizes, what options users have selected to add to the display of each object, etc. So the display code gets the area and then modifies it to handle the extra visual content. This is the one place where the app does this sort of thing.

Thanks for the advice about protocols and structures. I will investigate how I could use protocols for this and keep inheritance to a minimum. It's a porting project for a C++ app, and it's sometimes expedient to copy code when it doesn't need to change much.
